# How to publish carousel & story to Instagram from flutter app?

Tags: flutter, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I am building a flutter app where a user can share/publish media on their Instagram account. The app is already set up using Facebook SDK & publishing a single post (Image/Video) is working using graph API.
Now, I am having trouble with how to publish multiple images i.e Carousel or Story from the flutter app itself.There is no documentation i could get hands-on for integrating this.

Please help me with the implementation of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Carousels and stories are not available as part of the Content Publishing API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

> Stories are not supported.

> Multi-image posts are not supported.

Comment: I read this but there are applications doing the same eg: TRIBE Influencer. 
I am not sure how they are managing publishing multiple images & Stories. Can you help me with that?

Comment: They are either using a beta API or a non-official API.

Comment: Maybe, using unofficial APIs should be a problem though. Right?